# Does hostile juxtaposition work on my attacker?

Tags: pathfinder-1e, spells, combat, attack

[*Hostile juxtaposition*](http://paizo.com/pathfinderRPG/prd/ultimateCombat/spells/hostileJuxtaposition.html) will let me essentially swap places with another creature when attacked, allowing the attack to damage that creature instead. If the target of my *hostile juxtaposition* was the one attacking me and I activated it, would the target damage itself? This should work by RAW, and Ican see this working fine with regards to a ranged attacker, but will this allow me to swap places with somebody throwing a punch at me?

Comment: @HeyICanChan: I have no solid information to back that up with and am far from an expert on Pathfinder. If Hydrothermal asks, I'll do it, but otherwise, I'll wait for an expert.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

## "Stop hitting yourself!"

The description of the spell [*hostile juxtaposition*](http://paizo.com/pathfinderRPG/prd/ultimateCombat/spells/hostileJuxtaposition.html) does *not* say that the creature that's affected by the spell and the creature doing the attacking *must* be *different* creatures:

> When attacked or the subject of a spell that deals damage to you, you can spend an immediate action to cause yourself and the target creature to teleport and switch places. The target then becomes the target of the triggering attack or spell instead of you.

Thus, according to the rules, a creature can totally stab itself with its sword or be impaled by its own arrow. Even by strictly interpreting the rules for immediate actions, the spell *specifically* allows the immediate action to be taken upon being attacked but *before* damage is dealt.

(Note that in such a case the swapped-in creature's attack or spell isn't automatically *successful*; the creature merely becomes its own target. A swapped-in creature must, for example, still make a successful attack roll against itself or fail a saving throw against its own spell.)

### The GM may, however, still say *No*

Despite those being the rules, having a creature teleporting into its own sword blow may be disconcerting to a GM worried about the magic system's realism. Such a DM may argue, for example, that a creature *just can't* make an attack roll, teleport, and stab itself: "The spell would have to teleport the parts *making* the attack *after* the parts *being* attacked, and that's not what the spell says it does!" Although this GM finds such a stance on magic difficult, were I player in such a campaign it would take more than that single ruling to force me to leave the table.

Comment: Maybe it can teleport the subject without teleporting his weapon?  Still doesn't work for monks and natural attackers, but I could see a guy being teleported *onto* his sword being rather miffed that the sword he swung in front of him is now sticking out of his back.

Comment: @gatherer818 Yeah, maybe it's, like, **really fast** [*Portal*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Portal_(video_game))-like hilarity? I have no idea.